# SnowFlake DB deployment with GitLab-CI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gitlab-ci, cicd, dbdeploy

I have multiple Snowflake accounts, having the DB creations and Stored procedures available on GitLab repo. Is there a right approach available to deploy the same using GitLab-CI where DB deploy versions can also be tracked and DB-RollBack also will be feasible.

As of now I am trying with Python on pipeline to connect snowflake and to execute SQL-Script files, and to rollback as well specific SQL are needed for clean-ups and rollback where on-demand rollback becomes a challenge.

Looking for a right approach or sample to refer.

Comment: GitHub actions is something that you can look out for this requirement: https://medium.com/snowflake/snowflake-ci-cd-with-github-actions-c2168ceb33bc 
https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/devops_dcm_schemachange_github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Comment: Hi @SrinathMenon,
In case GitHub is used along with Azure-DataFactory, MS has its recommended ways, where GitHub is used exactly as AzureRepo with Azure-DataFactory. When its GitLab, and GitLab-CI, thats somthing I am looking for a recommendations, instead of cloning a GitHub/Azure-Repo and getting the triggers from it to Run a GitLab-CI pipeline.